# Determining whether $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^3 \left(x\right)}{\sqrt {x^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x $ converges or diverges.

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I's struggling with an integral, and not sure wich method I should use to determining whether it converges or diverges.

I know, from a software, that it should converge.

The integral is:
$$
\displaystyle\int_{1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{\sin^3 \left(x\right)}{\sqrt {x^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

I've been looking all over the forum for some clues with no success.
Maybe I'm not using the right function to compare.

It's the square root (of a square number) in the denominator that's puzzling me. Why did the text book made this writting? Maybe it's reffering to the modulus function?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2} = x$ when $x \in [1, +\infty[$

Comment: The integrand converges but contains the gamma function when resolved.

Comment: The integrand is not integrable in the sense of Lebesgue (the prove is similar as what you would do for $\frac{\sin x}{x}$. I guess you are interested in whether $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\int^x_1\frac{\sin^3 t}{t}\,dt$ exists. If so, maybe you want to edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Actually, @OliverDiaz , it's just a case to define and make an argument that proves if it converges or diverges. I'm not interested in the real integral value, because it would much like involves the gamma function. I'm studying several cases of convergence/divergence when we're not able to find the integral value through elementar functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $\sin 3x = 3 \sin x - 4 \sin^3 x \implies$

$$\int_1^c \frac{\sin^3 x}{x} \, dx = \frac{3}{4}\int_1^c \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx - \frac{1}{4}\int_1^c \frac{\sin 3x}{x} \, dx$$

Comment: Wow, that's actually a great idea. I'm gonna try to work with it and see where it should lead. Thank you, @RRL

Comment: @RafaelBarbosadaSilva: I'm sure you know that $\lim_{c \to \infty}\int_1^c \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx = \int_1^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx $ -- that is the improper integral converges.